# PHP - Updating or Creating Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, json

In my code I am checking if two variables are false. If both are false, then I want to update an array called responseArray with the value. I am unable to figure out how to update the array twice without overwriting the value if both variables are false. This is being used to capture if username and email address already registered.

Here is the code:

```
if($usernameAvailable == false)
    {
      /*Update validation error array that username taken*/
      if(isset($responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation']))
      {
        /*Already another validation error exist in the array, add to it*/
        $utilitiesInstance->array_push_assoc($responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation'], "Username", "Username Already Taken");
      }else{
        /*No array with validation errors is created...create it.*/
        $responseArray = array("ErrorArray"=>array("Validation"=>array("Username"=>"Username Already Taken")), "requestSuccessful"=>false);
      }
    }

    if($emailAvailable == false)
    {
      /*Update validation error array that Email already registered*/
      if(isset($responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation']))
      {
        /*Already another validation error exist in the array, add to it*/
        $utilitiesInstance->array_push_assoc($responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation'], "Email", "Email Already Registered");
      }else{
        /*No array with validation errors is created...create it.*/
        $responseArray = array("ErrorArray"=>array("Validation"=>array("Email"=>"Email Already Registered")), "requestSuccessful"=>false);
      }
    }
```

What I am getting when I enter both username and email that deliver a false on both is the following output:

> {"ErrorArray":{"Validation":{"Username":"Username Already
>   Taken"}},"requestSuccessful":false}

while it should also include the email item in the Validation array above because that also is false. This is exactly what I want to have as an output in this scenario:

> {"ErrorArray":{"Validation":{"Username":"Username Already Taken",
>   "Email":"Email already registered"}},"requestSuccessful":false}

Here is the code I use for the function array_push_assoc() just in case:

```
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mate:

```
if($usernameAvailable == false) {
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation'][] = array("Username"=>"Username Already Taken");
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['requestSuccessful'] = false;
}

if($emailAvailable == false) {
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation'][] = array("Email"=>"Email Already Registered");
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['requestSuccessful'] = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick although it modifies the structure of the arrays. Will wait for Steve to share his perspective. If none, then I will select this as an answer as it solves the problem.

Comment: No problem mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your array push method returns a copy of the array passed to it, it has no effect on the original array `$responseArray`.

To fix that change your method to take a reference to the array and make the changes in place:

```
function array_push_assoc_inplace(&$array, $key, $value)
{
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

However, most of the code seems unnecessary, you could simply use the following for the same result:

```
if($usernameAvailable == false){
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation']['Username']='Username Already Taken';
}
if($emailAvailable == false){
    $responseArray['ErrorArray']['Validation']['Email']='Email Already Registered';
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I end up with this array instead: {"Username":"Username Already Taken","Email":"Email Already Registered"} which lost most of the structure needed

Comment: @ksjg edited. Though this could still be imporved upon a lot, ill make another edit with a better method shortly

Comment: Sure I will wait for the better method because the above return null only. Thanks for helping out

Comment: What returns null?

Comment: I modified the code to use the new function defined above but the return is null.